# How to update a debian package for a python program with a setup.py

Tags: python, packaging

For the first time, the command `dh_make` will create all necessary files and directories and  this can be packaged with `debuild -S`.

After I make some changes, am I supposed to manually update the `debian` folder (changelog, control etc.), or is there a command similar to `dh_make` which will incorporate all the changes (except, maybe, the changelog) in the files in the `debian` directory?